# Using C# Expressions to build Array.All for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression, linq-expressions

I'm building a SQL "WHERE" clause dynamically using the System.Linq.Expressions.Expression class.

There are two tables
Report and Document with relation one to many

```cs
public class Report
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Documents>? Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Documents
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public Report? Report { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Linq Query to be replaced by Expression:

```cs
query.Where(x => x.Report.Documents.All(c =>( c.Type =="R" || c.Type =="RX") && c.Year==x.Report.Year))
```

What I archived so far is

```cs
private Expression GetExpression(Expression memberExpression)
{
   Expression<Func<ICollection<Documents>, bool>> containsExpr 
                    = (ICollection<Documents> q) => q.All((Func<Documents, bool> )null);
   var containsMethod = (containsExpr.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;
                       Expression<Func<Documents, bool>> contains = x => x.Type =="R";
                      
   MemberExpression collectionPropertyAccessor = Expression.Property(memberExpression, "Documents");
  var targetCodesContains = Expression.Call(containsMethod, collectionPropertyAccessor, contains);
  return  binaryExpression =  Expression.And(targetCodesContains, targetCodesContains);
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem here? can you please post the calling context of the query code that you posted?

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: BinaryExpression

Comment: I *assume* that `searchValues` should be converted into these `c.Type =="R" || c.Type =="RX"` predicates, but you should be 100% clear on that.

Comment: I do not understand question. Do you want to create similar predicate dynamically? Property always is `Type`? What you are building at the end?